# More up-to-date combat mechanics?

Tags: imperator-rome

The combat mechanics described on the Imperator: Rome wiki ([here](https://imperator.paradoxwikis.com/Damage_formula)) are out of date, last verified for version 1.4. Although most of them are plausible, the morale damage section in particular seems very wrong, as it lists a maximum morale of 4 - quite implausible since base unit morale is 3 and every level of military tech increases your armies' moral by 0.075, meaning you reach unit morale 4 by - at the latest, assuming no other bonuses from national Military Experience, Military Traditions, Heritages, and so on - tech level 14 or so, which is achievable quite early in the game.

Does anyone know how damage and combat mechanics work in Imperator: Rome version 2.0+?